# convert NSString to int value using NSScanner

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have the following code which converts decimal value to string.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:intValue];
NSString* actualString;
int code;
[scanner scanInt:&code];
actualString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unsigned short)code] copy];
```

using this i will get actual string.

Now how can I revert to get the intValue back again.

Regards,

Comment: Why copy? Nobody will change `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unsigned short)code]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int actualCode = *(const unsigned short*)[actualString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```